# How large is a fey beast's aura?

Tags: dnd-4e, aura

This might be a stupid question because I can't find the answer anywhere..  How large is the aura of a fey beast companion?  I'm considering making a Fey Beast Tamer.

Also, can you use a fey beast companion to flank a target and gain combat advantage like with ranger companions?  Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're playing Dungeons and Dragons, I'm also guessing your playing 4e? Please make sure to tag the game properly

Answer (score 5):

The Fey beasts from the [Fey Beast Tamer background](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=Theme&id=915) all have an Aura 1 power. (that means they affect the squares around them). This is defined by the beast, not the background, so their entries are the source material here.

And yes, they count as allies for flanking.

> Your fey beast companion is considered an ally of you and your allies. It can be affected by powers in the same way that any other creature can be. It has animal intelligence, so you can communicate with it only at a basic level (like a trained pet), and it doesn’t understand complex ideas.

Lastly since not everyone has DDI, this is all from Heroes of the Feywild pp106-107.

Comment: +1 thanks for including page numbers. As one of those non-ddi people, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ColinD yeah, something I've been trying to do more often, as they are listed right in the DDI articles so it shouldn't be hard to add them in.